# How do I replace all the / in a URL with ,?

Tags: javascript, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to convert a URL input to a suitable format for my api and have run into an issue.
Whenever I perform a global search and replace using `(/blue/g, "red");` it works fine.

But whenever I try to do the same operation, but with slashes (`(///g, "red");`) it gives me a
syntax error.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Try regex to replace this - `srt.replace(/\//g, ',')`

Comment: can you add a minimal example and the error into the question ?

Comment: Sorry actually I tried it out and it worked

Comment: and maybe replaceAll() is more suitable here?

Comment: @Alex But OP's code works as well. Did you get a Syntax error with OP's code?

Comment: @Alex

I made a bit of a mistake, the question has been updated!

Comment: Thanks for the update. The error makes much more sense now. And Alex's suggestion is now correct and to the point: you need to escape your slash if you write it in between slashes.

Comment: Here's the og code:
`var pathFormatted = pathInput.replace("/", ",")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var strings = "yellow/red/blue";
console.log(strings);
strings = strings.replace(/\//g,",");
console.log(strings);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for replace / by , in URL:

Here is the solution for it:

```js
const windowURL= 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318599/how-do-i-replace-all-the-in-a-url-with';
const URL = new URL(windowURL);
const path = URL.pathname.replaceAll('/', ',')

console.log('Updated path in which `/` is replaced by `,` =>>', path)
```